# Removing zeros without removing entire row or col - R

Tags: r, row, zero, col

Is there any way to make the first column start by the first positive value?
Suppose I have a data like this

[image]

and I want it to look like this:

[image]

Obviously my data is much bigger and to do it manually it's very tedious. I've search about this, but can only find ways to remove rows or columns based on zeros.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Help others help you: Create an [mcve]. In particular, it would be helpful if you [edit] your question to include the output of `dput(x)`, where `x` is the name of your data frame or matrix. (Or `dput(head(x))` for a subset).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude elements equal to zero and adapt the `length` row-wise.

```
t(mapply(`length<-`, apply(m, 1, function(x) x[x != 0]), ncol(m)))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    7    9    4   NA
# [2,]    3    6   NA   NA   NA
# [3,]    1    6    6    4    3
# [4,]    7   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [5,]    4    3    1    8   NA
```

If your data is a data frame,

```
d <- as.data.frame(m)
```

you may do:

```
setNames(as.data.frame(t(mapply(`length<-`, apply(d, 1, function(x) x[x != 0]), ncol(d)))),
         names(d))
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
# 1  1  7  9  4 NA
# 2  3  6 NA NA NA
# 3  1  6  6  4  3
# 4  7 NA NA NA NA
# 5  4  3  1  8 NA
```

---

*Data*

```
m <- matrix(c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
              1, 0, 6, 0, 4,
              7, 0, 6, 0, 3,
              9, 3, 4, 0, 1,
              4, 6, 3, 7, 8), 5)
```